# Is there a way to make all the multimedia for a CommCare application read-only?

Tags: commcare

Is there some way to make all the multimedia for a CommCare application read-only?

What is happening is that, users are trying to free up space and are removing multimedia from the phone's memory which is referenced in the application. This is not affecting the application (not crashing) but the icons/videos/audio is not available anymore in the app.

The only way out of it is that we re-install the application altogether.

How do other commercial applications handle this (like I can't go delete the icons or other stuff for something like Uber) or is the fact that CommCare does an install from a .ccz file make that impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Without rooting the device I'm not sure of a good way of making any folder read only.

One option could be to place a `.nomedia` file in the folder where the multimedia is located. This will prevent Android from scanning the folder for media and hence it won't show up in any albums etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered, but I'll provide some additional context.

> How do other commercial applications handle this (like I can't go
>   delete the icons or other stuff for something like Uber)

The reason CommCare's media appears differently to the device is that most applications store their media within the application's resources (inside the 'APK' file), which are out of reach for the user.

Since CommCare is dynamically generating those resources based on your app from an external source (the 'CCZ' file), those files are stored directly onto the file system.